# "open | $filex" couldn't execute existing file on windows only

Tags: windows, file, tcl, mobaxterm, tcltk

Below code:

```
set filex "./run.sh"

if {[file exist $filex]} {
    puts "File exist!"
}

if {[catch {open |$filex r} pipe]} {
    puts "pwd = [pwd]"
    puts "ERROR: $pipe"
}
```

returns followind message:

> File exist!
>   pwd = F:/
>   ERROR: couldn't execute ".\run.sh": no such file or directory

The problem is absent in linux OS (script is normally run), appears only in Windows (on CygWin too). The permissions of the file is: 777. Any universal workaround for both OS?

Comment: Have you tried running it manually on Windows?

Comment: Are you launching tclsh from the cygwin environment?

Comment: Yes, I have tried running it manuallu on Windows and launching it from the CygWin environment, the output is exactly the same.

Comment: Can you run that script from _outside_ the cygwin environment?

Comment: Yes, I can. Calling command in batch (call .\run.sh) run usr/bin/bash from mintty terminal.

Comment: There's something subtle going on (and I'm not on the right platform to test things out). What does `autoexec_ok $filex` return for that file? Does `open |[autoexec_ok $filex]` work?

Comment: auto_execok $filex - works perfectly.  if {[catch {open "|auto_execok $filex" r} pipe]} returns: ERROR: couldn't execute "auto_execok": no such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found workaround for this problem by adding bash after '|' character:

```
if {[catch {open "|bash $filex" r} pipe]} {
```